# how can I animate points between sectors of polar axis?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to animate a circle travelling on an arch around sectors in a polar graph (e.g. quarters of a circle, pie pieces). In the image below, the animation would move a single circle from point 1 to 2, then from 2 to 3, and so on until the circle travels from 5 to 6.

[image: unsuccessful polar animation]

So far, I'm unable to make the shape a circle and the movement isn't happening between sectors.

After much experimenting and googling I haven't been able to find any pointers on how to define the location of `patch.center` in `init()` appropriately, and how to update it in `animate()` so that it travels in sequence from 1 to 6, as explained above. I saw in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19828753/) that adding the parameter `transform=ax.transData._b` to `plt.Circle()` makes it a circle, but then on animation I get the error `ValueError: The shortcut cannot be computed since other's transform includes a non-invertable component.`.

Any pointers are appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

r_list = [1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3] 
theta_list = [1.5707963267948966, 0.7853981633974483, -3.9269908169872414, 0.0, 3.141592653589793, -0.7853981633974483]


def cart2pol(x, y):
    rho = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
    return(rho, phi)

def pol2cart(rho, phi):
    x = rho * np.cos(phi)
    y = rho * np.sin(phi)
    return(x, y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)


####### used only to clearly label intended travel #######

c = plt.scatter(theta_list, r_list)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
labels=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
for i, txt in enumerate(labels):
    ax.annotate(txt, (theta_list[i], r_list[i]))

##########################################################

patch = plt.Circle(pol2cart(r_list[0], theta_list[0]), 0.5, alpha=0.5)

def init():
    patch.center = (pol2cart(r_list[0], theta_list[0]))
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    return patch,


def animate(i):
    x, y = patch.center
    x, y = (pol2cart(r_list[i%6], theta_list[i%6]))
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 
                               init_func=init, 
                               frames=360, 
                               interval=200,
                               blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to the following code, use `scatter()` to draw the circle, and set the center of the circle by `set_offsets()` method:

```
patch = plt.scatter(theta_list[0], r_list[0], 600, alpha=0.5)

def init():
    patch.set_offsets([[theta_list[0], r_list[0]]])
    return patch,

def animate(i):
    patch.set_offsets([[theta_list[i % 6], r_list[i % 6]]])
    return patch,
```

the plot is looking like this:

[image]