# How to plot circles in polar plot in python

Tags: python, scatter

I have a list with `x`,`y`,`z`, `r` coordinates (cartesians). I need to plot some circles in a polar plot, but I don't know how to do it with cartesians coordinates.

I am trying to do it with this line

`circle1 = plt.Circle((x[i], y[i]), r[i], transform=ax3.transData._b, color = 'r', alpha=0.5, fill=False)`

but this doesn't seem to work because I obtain the circles too far away from the center of the origin.

any help?

```
data1 = pd.read_csv('Uchuu_lightcone_0_11.9_voids.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

x = data1[0]
y = data1[1]
r = data1[3]
z = data1[2]
azvoids, elvoids, rvoids = cart2sph(x,y,z)
d = ax3.scatter(azvoids, rvoids, s=3, c='red', alpha=1, marker='.')
for i in range(len(x)):
    if elvoids[i] > 35 and elvoids[i] < 45:
        circle1 = plt.Circle((x[i], y[i]), r[i], transform=ax3.transData._b, color = 'r', alpha=0.5, fill=False)
        ax3.add_artist(circle1)


#  The cart2sph function is

def cart2sph(x,y,z):
    """ x, y, z :  ndarray coordinates
        ceval: backend to use: 
              - eval :  pure Numpy
              - numexpr.evaluate:  Numexpr """
    azimuth = arctan2(y,x)*180/math.pi
    xy2 = x**2 + y**2
    elevation = arctan2(z, sqrt(xy2))*180/math.pi
    r = sqrt(xy2 + z**2)
    return azimuth, elevation, r
```

Comment: does this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827792/matplotlib-drawing-a-smooth-circle-in-a-polar-plot

Comment: Can you put a minimal example?

Comment: @LSeu no it doesn't, I've written the same as in the example and when I plot the center of the circles and the circles I don't get the centers right in the center of the circles

Comment: @ymmx added to the original post!

Answer (score 1):

You should use azvoids and rvoids to plot the center of the circle since you use those to show tham in the scatter plot

```
import  math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

def cart2sph(x, y, z):
    """ x, y, z :  ndarray coordinates
        ceval: backend to use:
              - eval :  pure Numpy
              - numexpr.evaluate:  Numexpr """
    azimuth = np.arctan2(y, x) * 180 / math.pi
    xy2 = x ** 2 + y ** 2
    elevation = np.arctan2(z, np.sqrt(xy2)) * 180 / math.pi
    r = np.sqrt(xy2 + z ** 2)
    return azimuth, elevation, r

#
# data1 = pd.read_csv('Uchuu_lightcone_0_11.9_voids.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
# data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

N=100
x = (np.random.rand(N)-0.5)*100
y = (np.random.rand(N)-0.5)*100
z = (np.random.rand(N)-0.5)*100
r = np.random.rand(N)*10
azvoids, elvoids, rvoids = cart2sph(x, y, z)
fig = plt.figure()
ax3 = plt.subplot(111 )
d = plt.scatter(azvoids, elvoids, s=3 , c='red', alpha=1, marker='.' )
for i in range(len(x)):
    if elvoids[i] > 35 and elvoids[i] < 45:
        # circle1 = plt.Circle((azvoids[i], elvoids[i]), rvoids[i], color='r', alpha=0.5, fill=False)

        x, y =  ax3.transData.transform((azvoids[i], elvoids[i]))
        trans = (fig.dpi_scale_trans +
                 transforms.ScaledTranslation(azvoids[i], elvoids[i], ax3.transData))
        circle1 = plt.Circle((azvoids[i], elvoids[i]), rvoids[i]  , color='r', alpha=0.5, fill=None)
        ax3.add_artist(circle1)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
#  The cart2sph function is
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work neither. However, I thought transform=ax3.transData._b did that work for me

Comment: I eliminated the part transform=ax3.transData._b changed x, y for azvoids[i] rvoids[i] and now something appears but not spheres

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your issue. I edited the post to make equal scale for both axis so you get real circle and not ellipses. can you explain what you expect as output?

Comment: I have two files, one with galaxies and other with voids... They are both in cartesians coordinates and I need first to convert this cartesians coordinates to spherical ones (that's the def cart2sph) and then I need to plot these galaxies as points and these voids as circles (forget about el coordinate) as well as voids centers

Comment: Why do you need to convert to spherical coordinate? the issue is that you have a point in 3D and you try to display them in 2D so you need to make a projection.

Comment: I updated the answer with a polar plot directly.

Comment: If I do copy and paste of that none circle appear in my plot and galaxies are forgotten

Comment: In addition, I don't want to use the elavation, and I think the plot is doing anything with it too, I only want to plot the azimutal coordinate and the radial coordinate, and the radius of the voids of course